# C - Losing pointee struct values

Tags: c, pointers, struct, reset, ghosts-in-the-machine

**Updated. Sorry to those whose answers no longer make sense.

So I figured out that no matter what I put on the line after Data_pair_node, after it executes, thats when the thing is reset! WTH? :

```
int insert(Table *t, const char *key, const char *val){
 int dest_bucket_index;
 Table *table = t;
 Hash_bucket *dest_bucket = NULL;
 Data_pair_node *current = NULL, *prev = NULL, *new_item = NULL;

 printf("gonna be zero now");
```

Lo and behold:

```
$23 = (Hash_bucket *) 0x834010
(gdb) step
109  printf("gonna be zero now");
(gdb) print table->buckets
$24 = (Hash_bucket *) 0x0
```

Thanks
Aymon Fournier

Comment: If your average_list_len function is not changing the contents of the pointer passed to it, define it as taking a pointer to const data: `double average_list_len(const Table *table)` and let the compiler help you validate the workings of the function.

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't zero *before* you called the function?  Are your linked lists definitely correct?  (i.e. have you confirmed they don't inadvertently point to random bits of memory?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an integer divide (both list_count and table->bucket_ct are ints), so your result will be truncated and you'll get a return value of 0 if the average bucket list length is less than 1.0 -- if you have more buckets in the hash table than entries.

Since you want a double answer, it makes more sense to use a double divide:

```
ret = (double)list_count / table->bucket_ct;
```

**edit**

It's tough to tell what's going on as you never print out the value of `table` or show the code that calls `insert` (which is where it gets its value).  But a couple of things might be going on.

- `table` is a local var so the compiler might put it in a register and reuse that register for something else once `table` is dead (after the last use in the code), in which case printing `table` at that point (or anything depending on it) with gdb might print anything.
- if `table` is a dangling pointer into the stack (it comes from another function that returned the address of a local variable), it might well be pointing at memory used for some other local vars, in which case assigning to those local vars will change the value of `table->buckets`

Comment: Dangling pointer. Thanks for that thorough explanation. I found it.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the `average_list_len` function. The only way for it to return zero is if the table has zero buckets to begin with.

Your `insert` function's code shows you don't modify the values of the table, so i'd say your table has zero buckets at the time the `insert` function is called.

You should inspect (or post?) the rest of the call stack. On a side note, i recommend gdb as a nice console debugger :)

Comment: I found out that it wasn't happening there, and posted my updated question with gdb.